# Why crontab can't start the safari driver

Tags: python, selenium, cron

Last night, I'm trying to use selenium with python to make a script fill the body temperature in the website which given by my college

But when I want to use crontab to automatically execute the script, it's always report an error like this

```
  File "/Users/clay_codes1024/PythonProject/FillTemperature.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Safari()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/safari/webdriver.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

here is my Python code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

account = ''
password = ''
temperature = ''

driver = webdriver.Safari()

driver.get('')

driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(account)

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id("password").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_id("passbutton").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[18]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/input').clear()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[18]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/input').send_keys(temperature)
time.sleep(2)

# use javascript to click the log in button
js = 'document.getElementById("post").click();'
driver.execute_script(js)
time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

what I have done:

```
1. Give the full disk access to Python3, crontab, terminal

2. Use shell script to execute the python script like this
echo 'password' | sudo -S /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/clay_codes1024/PythonProject/FillTemperature.py

3. Turn on the 'Allow remote automation' in safari
```

All above didn't work!

So pls help me

Huge thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Seeing similar error with pm2. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667714